# Use the Lagrange multiplier method to compute the maximum value of the function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Use the Lagrange multiplier method to compute the maximum value of the function $h(x,y,z) = x+z$ on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

My attempt:

∇h = (1,0,1) = λ(2x,2y,2z)

This implies x = z and y = 0

It follows that $2z^2=1$, meaning $z=\pm \sqrt{0.5} = x$

Testing :

$h(\sqrt{0.5}, 0, \sqrt{0.5}) = 2\sqrt{0.5}$

$h(-\sqrt{0.5},0,\sqrt{0.5}) = -2\sqrt{0.5}$

So the maximum value is at $(\sqrt{0.5}, 0, \sqrt{0.5})$

Comment: Looks good. What's the question?

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer is on the right track!

Comment: It is. $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. You solved it, all you have to do is evaluate $h$ at the point$(\sqrt (1/2),0,\sqrt(1/2))$

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know that I have worked it out correctly :)